# rethrow exceptions in handler code using uncaught_exceptions()

Tags: c++, exception

During stack unwind it is possible to check how many exceptions has not been handled.

*What should this be used for or should I not use it?*

*uncaught_exceptions*() returns the number of exceptions currently active. Where active means thrown or rethrown but not yet handled.

I understand that you can check during stack unwind if you want to terminate the program or handle the exception and set the program back to a good state and (or retry). 
Specifically this might be the case in destructors where I can guarantee not to throw exceptions.

On the same note Bjarne Stroustrup [mentions](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) in hos book that it is bad practice to rethrow in exception handler code since we very easily get into a situation where terminate is called.

[N3614 unwinding_exception](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3614.pdf)

[N4152 uncaught_exceptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf)

[N4259 Wording for std::uncaught_exceptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4259.pdf)

[GotW #47](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm)

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was needed to make SCOPE_GUARD (from Andrei' cppcon 2015 talk) work correctly. Thats one example that I can remember of...

Comment: The idea is that it could be useful to compare the number of exceptions active when an object is created to the number of exceptions active in the destructor. If it has increased, perhaps it is time to surrender? If not, we might just be part of some other code's cleanup activity.